# Azure DevOps Pipeline - Pushing to Azure Container Registry - Permission error

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-container-registry

- I have created an Azure Container Registry.
- I have an Azure DevOps project.
- I have created an Azure DevOps Pipeline using the wizard so
  that it uses the standard template to build and push a Docker image.

When validating the Pipeline the following error is thrown:

> Failed to set Azure permission 'RoleAssignmentId: ****' for the service principal '****' on subscription ID '****': error code: Forbidden, inner error code: AuthorizationFailed, inner error message The client '****' with object id '****' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over scope '/subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/****/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/****/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/****' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials. Ensure that the user has 'Owner' or 'User Access Administrator' permissions on the Subscription.

What configuration could I be missing? The documentation for this is all very sparse and written as though it should all just work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `AcrPull` permission to service principal you used here. Please got to you ACR and add it.

Here you have id of you service principal:

> Failed to set Azure permission 'RoleAssignmentId: ****' for the service principal '****'

Also please check also networking on ACR if it blocks you or not.

Answer (score 0):

To build and push your Docker image in Azure pipeline, you need follow the steps below:

1. Navigate to **Project Settings** > **Service connections** to create a [Docker Registry service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#docker-hub-or-others) that can connect to your ACR.

   [image]
2. In the pipeline, add the [Docker task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops) to build and push your Docker image to ACR.

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Yours service principal on service connection is missing permissions link to documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-roles?tabs=azure-cli. You can use custom role or build like contributor on resource group level. Example of custom role and allowed actions "Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/push/write",